# Form : 2 Separate Paths

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am working on a simple form for work. I found some code online and have been working with it. It starts out asking a simple question. If the student has an ID? It is a toggle of either "YES" or "NO". If "Yes" is selected then it will pull student info from a database and display. If "NO" then separate boxes will pop up asking for the students ID, last name, first name, DOB, etc. Right now I am focusing on the path selection to work. I haven't had any luck.

```js
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect) {
  if (nameSelect) {
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
    if (admOptionValue == nameSelect.value) {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
Student ID
<select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
  <option value="6"></option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option id="admOption" value="0">No</option>

</select>


<div id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
  <br><br>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    Please enter ID# <input type="number" name="ID"><br> Last Name <input type="text" name="last"><br> First Name <input type="text" name="first"><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is. Please expand a little more

Comment: Sure no problem. So when I select "NO" it performs what I want it to, it brings up the user input to enter more information. If I select "YES" I want it to do something similar, bringing up some more user inputs. Right now I am unable to get "YES" to populate anything. Please let me know if I can further clarify.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? .

```js
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect) {
 
 var value = nameSelect.value;

 if (value == "1") {
  document.getElementById("id-form").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("second-div").style.display = "none";
 } else if (value == "0"){
  document.getElementById("id-form").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second-div").style.display = "block";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("id-form").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("second-div").style.display = "none";
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "test.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  Student ID
  <select id="getFname" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
   <option value="6"></option>
   <option value="1">Yes</option>
   <option id="admOption" value="0">No</option>
  </select>

  <form id = "id-form" action="/action_page.php" method="post" style = "display: none">
   Please enter ID# <input type="number" name="ID"><br> 
   Last Name <input type="text" name="last"><br>
   First Name <input type="text" name="first">
   <br>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <div id = "second-div" style = "display: none">
   <br>
   <img src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QuTLRz8Nli0/hqdefault.jpg"/>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```